# Bootstrap: How do I make the hamburger visible at breakpoint and hide navbar for all other screen sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, navbar, hamburger-menu, breakpoint-sass

I would like to hide the navbar for all screen sizes, except 480px and smaller screen sizes where I would like the "hamburger" to be displayed. How can I achieve this?  Thank you.

Comment: Where is your navbar code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **visible-xs** class on your div. E.g.,

```
<div class="visible-xs any-other-class-you-may-have">
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query..

```
.navbar {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .navbar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/TzpIH3b0uH